# Using alias to shorten my command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am used to searching specific keywords under Linux.

For example, I may search "TAIWAN" under home by

```
grep -i -r TAIWAN ./ | grep -v".svn"
```

However, I thought this is a little redundant; I want to use an alias so I can type

```
grep TAIWAN
```

and then the alias will expand my command into

```
grep -i -r TAIWAN ./ | grep -v".svn"
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to do it with an *alias*, but you can create a bash *function*:

```
mygrep () { grep -i -r $* ./ | grep -v".svn"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe alias can accomplish what you want because there is no way to reorder the arguments.  It is simpler to make a small shell command.  Rather than replace `grep`, and thus possibly mess up programs which expect `grep` to behave in a certain way, I'd give it a new name such as `rgrep`.

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -i -r "$@" | grep -v .svn
```

Put that somewhere in your `PATH` such as `~/bin` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/rgrep`.  Then you can `rgrep TAIWAN .`.

Unfortunately, this will ignore *lines* which contain `.svn` as well as files.

You could try to fix up the `grep -v` pattern match to only match the file part of the grep output, or you could whip up a more complicated command using `find` instead of `grep -r`... or you can use ack.

[Ack](http://betterthangrep.com) is a better grep and will avoid version control directories and other common files and directories you don't care about.  It will also automatically use a pager and color the output.